# Creating Menutem in Cocos2d Windows phoneI

Tags: cocos2d-x

I want to add a Sprite as well as Label in a Single menuItem with both are clickable but In C# you cannot extend from more than one class.

I extend from menuItemLabel class and Compose the Class with menuItemSprite.

But when I click on Label it is working fine but MenuItemSprite is not responding to the click event.

If anyone knows the solution to this problem kindly reply to this.

```
public class menuitem4 : CCMenuItemLabel
{
    public static menuitem4 itemwith(CCNode normal, CCNode selected, CCNode label, SelectorProtocol target, SEL_MenuHandler selector)
    {
        menuitem4 pRet = new menuitem4();
        pRet.a = CCMenuItemLabel.itemWithLabel(label,target, selector);
        Specie1Store sp = (Specie1Store)target;
        pRet.a.position = new CCPoint(500,100);
        sp.addChild(pRet.a);
        pRet.initWithLabel(label, target, selector);
        return pRet;
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot understand, what fo you want to do. you want to place two buttons at the same position and get both click events with single touch? or you just want to add titlt to your button?

Comment: I want two buttons in one line and want to be both clickable as single item.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that extends CCNode and add CCMenuItemImage and CCMenuItemLabel as children.